# Load and Save JSON file react client-side only

Tags: json, web, react-redux

I am building a simple editor-type application in react-redux, and I want to mimic the operation of downloading and uploading json files for saving and loading data - entirely client side. The server side does not need the data. Local storage may be too small, and it would be nice to provide the user the data in a portable file they could upload on a new machine. Is this even possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

Using a `blob` file.

You can set the content of a new file which is temp and local, then trigger a click event to download the file.

[duplicate answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156282/how-do-i-save-json-to-local-text-file) [and here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46023112/export-json-to-json-file)

Comment: I appreciate your attempt at an answer, but of the 3 possibilities provided, only 1 performs the download behavior I want - and it doesn't work. I think browsers are now blocking dynamically clicking links. Additionally, your answer does not address the upload behavior at all - but I figured that one out.